# How do I make Node.js reference the CSS for my HTML

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I am trying to create a Turn Based strategy game like EU4 in JS. I would like to include multiplayer functionality but I want to understand why this keeps happening: When I run my app through node it seems to be that it only shows the bare HTML and not the CSS. Please help.

Code Below:

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var serv = require('http').Server(app)
var port = 2000

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html')
})

app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'))

serv.listen(port)
console.log('Colonial Warfare server => initialized!')
console.log('CWserver HostPort: ' + port)


var io = require('socket.io') (serv,{})
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket connection')
})
```

Comment: Can you show how are you importing the css in the html?

Comment: `<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Colonial Warfare</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/gameStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/militaryUnitStyle.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./img/mainIcon.png">

</head>`

Comment: thats the HTML part

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the static CSS files by replacing the get for your index.html with the following line:

app.use(express.static('public'))

Change 'public' to 'client' if the CSS is next to your index.HTML.

Details here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

--EDIT--

As the index.html includes the css like "/css/filename.css" you have to host it like this:
app.use(express.static('css'))
or you change the references to your stylesheets to /client/css/filename.css in your html file.
Whenever you access an (for express) unknown path, express returns the index.html file.

Comment: It did not seem to work. I get this message from the console. `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:2000/css/gameStyle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: as you try to access the css via /css/gameStyle.css in your index.html you have to either serve the (express root/)css folder (if available) or you have to change the reference in your html to "/client/css/gameStyle.css". the error message you get is the result of express, as it serves the index.html page (with mime type text/html) whenever an unknown path is requested.

Answer (score 0):

When your browser send the http request "/" you return your html that links to "/css/gameStyle.css".

You can either move your css folder to the client folder and change the link to "/client/css/gameStyle.css".

Or you can serve your css folder on the node app `app.use(express.static('css'))`